# html css basic navigation menu not working on hover

Tags: html, css, navbar

I just want this navigation to work normally.

```
<li class="nav-item" data-magellan-arrival="restaurant-menu" title="Restaurant Menu><a     class="scroll" href="#restaurant-menu">Menu </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Breakfast</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lunch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dinner</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I want breakfast lunch and dinner to pop out when I hover over "Menu". 
When I style the `<ul>` with `display:none;` it never comes out and otherwise it shows all the time... Thanks.

Some CSS:

```
.nav-bar > li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 39px;}

ul.flyout, .nav-bar li ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;}

.top-bar ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  display: inline;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 10px;
  list-style: none;}
```

Comment: everybody feels like an idiot someday :)

Comment: Your `title` attribute has unclosed string. You have no `:hover` rule in your CSS, so how do you expect to get any hover effect?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle (www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.nav-item > ul > li{
    display: none;
}

.nav-item:hover > ul >li {
    display: block;
}
```

use the above code in

in this li is hidden when you hover on .nav-item it will show the hidden li

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.nav-item > ul {
  display: none;
}

.nav-item:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I made an example using your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jntahqkh/.  The `position: absolute;` should keep the submenu from interfering with the rest of the content on your site.   You might have to play around with it a bit to get it to display correctly in your site, but this should at least get you on the right path.  Also, this might not work on mobile devices (Android/iOS)...not sure how they handle :hover selectors or if they even do.